# What to get from vga=771 option. What is missing in lubuntu that ubuntu has by default

Tags: boot, lubuntu

@lenovo-ideapad110-ibr

I just got a successful boot to a fresh Lubuntu by using vga=771 after waves of usb lubuntu installation errors. nomodeset is still there by default.

When vga=771 is presented i got a white screen with cursor. i am able to go into terminal (All text is distorted and background is white again).

Ubuntu is working fine with this machine so what do i need to install or setup to get rid of vga=771 boot option. Which what i got is a manual frame buffer size value.

I used software updater. Nothing noticeable happened.

Comment: `vga=771` is deprecated. And it already was in 2010. You need to use `set gfxpayload=800x600x8,800x600` and Ubuntu is likely to have that set as a fallback in the installer or option in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @Rinzwind tried this `gfxpayload=800x600x8,800x600` same result. tried vga=771 again its working how can i find what vga=771 is getting rolled back ?

Comment: Is this a driver issue or broken lightdm ? my attempts of reinstalling lightdm is inconclusive. i am sure if i did it properly i dont know how to debug it.